# Synchronous generator

Tags: power, motor, generator, synchronous

[image]

While calculating this professor first said 200MVA and 25KVA are 1pu because they are rated values. Then he easily find the E filed by Efiled = Vterminal + Armature Current*total impedance(synchronous reactance in this case)

However, I am confused about this solution.

He didn't calculate the Vphase he directly said Vterminal is equal to 1pu.

Shouldn't we need to say Vterminal = 1/sqr(3) pu rather than 1 for this question?